# Github Pull-Request has 1k Commits rather than my 1 commit

Tags: git, github

How do I remove all the prior commits from my pull request?

I've tried an endless combination of branches and cherry-picks and resets and pulls and nothing seems to be working...

Comment: To see what commits will appear in a pull request, you can do `git log COMMIT_A..COMMIT_B` where `COMMIT_A` is the branch you're sending the pull request to and `COMMIT_B` is the branch you're asking to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

well your most recent pull request would only have the changes in that request. Do you want to just remove the other commits?

you could do `rm .git`

then `git init`

then `git push` to a new repo.